# TextLabels not changing to Visible = false to Visible = true

Tags: transparency, luau, textlabel, roblox-studio

So, i have a roblox game, and im trying to get a TextLabel to be visible 20 seconds later after you join the game. and yes, the IntValues Tower1Votes, Tower2Votes, Tower3Votes, do actually exists, and they do change values when you press another button in the game. By the way, All of the TextLabels are Transparent and are Visible.
So heres my code:

```
while wait(20) do
        if BunchID.Value == 1 then
            if Tower1Votes.Value > Tower2Votes.Value and Tower1Votes.Value > Tower3Votes.Value then
                ToCH.TextTransparency = ToCH.TextTransparency - 1
        end
        if Tower2Votes.Value > Tower1Votes.Value and Tower2Votes.Value > Tower3Votes.Value then
            NEAT.TextTransparency = ToIC.TextTransparency - 1
        end
        if Tower3Votes.Value > Tower1Votes.Value and Tower3Votes.Value > Tower2Votes.Value then
            ToCH.TextTransparency = ToIC.TextTransparency - 1
        end
    end
    if BunchID.Value == 2 then
        if Tower1Votes.Value > Tower2Votes.Value and Tower1Votes.Value > Tower3Votes.Value then
            ToFT.TextTransparency = ToIC.TextTransparency - 1
        end
        if Tower2Votes.Value > Tower1Votes.Value and Tower2Votes.Value > Tower3Votes.Value then
            ToKY.TextTransparency = ToIC.TextTransparency - 1
        end
        if Tower3Votes.Value > Tower1Votes.Value and Tower3Votes.Value > Tower2Votes.Value then
            ToJGF.TextTransparency = ToIC.TextTransparency - 1
        end
    end
    if BunchID.Value == 3 then
        if Tower1Votes.Value > Tower2Votes.Value and Tower1Votes.Value > Tower3Votes.Value then
            ToF.TextTransparency = ToIC.TextTransparency - 1
        end
        if Tower2Votes.Value > Tower1Votes.Value and Tower2Votes.Value > Tower3Votes.Value then
            ToAT.TextTransparency = ToIC.TextTransparency - 1
        end
        if Tower3Votes.Value > Tower1Votes.Value and Tower3Votes.Value > Tower2Votes.Value then
            ToL.TextTransparency = ToIC.TextTransparency - 1
        end 
    end
end
```

I tried to make them transparent by doing this: `TextLabel.Transparency =- 1` but it didn't work, even tho all of the IntValues can change. I have no errors in my script, so i don't know what is happening.

Comment: Is this a Script or a LocalScript? Can you share the code that defines all of these variables?